# MySQL ODBC - IM002

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I need to connect with my database on my server. I tested my server and everything is running really well and so I know, that this is not the problem.

If I want to connect to my database, it gives me out this error:

> (IM002) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

I have installed the MySQL ODBC Connector 5.1, for which the libary is use was made for (I dont really use a libary but a class a friend sent me a while ago).

How do I solve this error? I tried serveral things I found out via google, but nothing changes.

Comment: What I forgot: on other pcs it doesn't even work, but another program with this class everything works. Does nobody knows anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everybody who has this problem: for me it helped to install Microsoft ODBC Connector 5.1 **32** Bit.